# How to do block paste in VS Code like Visual Studio

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio, I can:

1. hold alt and drag my mouse to select a block
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it
3. at an arbitrary location, I can draw a similar rectangle using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + drag
4. Then I can hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it there.

Here's an example copying and pasting into empty space

[image]

How do I do that in Visual Studio *Code*?

Comment: By default, VS Code enables multi cursor mode the same way (Alt + mouse click).

Comment: but doesn't allow you to draw a rectangle in empty space as in the clip I shared.  That is the capability I'm looking for

Comment: That capability requires a feature known as "Virtual Space". Apparently, VS Code [doesn't support that](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960).

Comment: @IInspectable aha that's it. never heard the term before.  So on the back burner since 2016? oh well

Answer (score -1):

This operation is not supported in Visual Studio Code

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/13960